# What are Live tiles in Dashboards

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am quite new to Tableau !

I Wanted to know What are live Tiles? what are their advantages ?

**Does Tableau support this feature of [Live tiles something like this in dundas](http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard5.Design_HTML.ashx#__Best_practices_for_tile_design_7)**

What are the Other Tools having this feature ?

Please if somebody could help me on this ! i did alot of research with zero result !

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see of that Dundas link, a live tile is a miniature representation of a dashboard that contains some of the dashboard's key elements. Live tiles could thus be used in combination to give a summary/overview of important dashboards, where clicking on each tile would take you to that particular dashboard.

At present, I do not believe that Tableau Server supports such functionality. If this is functionality that would be useful to your organisation, then please feel free to [add an Idea to the Tableau Community Forum](http://community.tableausoftware.com/community/ideas/).

Comment: thanks for your answer ! do you know any other visualization tools that has this feature ?

Comment: I had a look around, but couldn't see anything that jumped out other than this question and the Dundas link. If this answer was useful, then please remember to accept it and upvote it when you have sufficient rep. :)